# How ot pass keys on RMI Sealed Object

Tags: java, rmi

Hi there I am trying to add some security to my rmi project we where told to use sealed object. I just cant figure out how to to use the keys how do I go about passing the client the key. This is what i have so far

```
package Server;

import application.ClientInterface;

import javax.crypto.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

/**
 * Created by alexi on 05/12/2016.
 */
public class MyFileServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInit, Serializable {

    private static Cipher ecipher;
    private static SecretKey key;


    public  MyFileServer() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void importFiles(ClientInterface n, String name) throws RemoteException {
        String videoPath = "src" + File.separator + "Videos" + File.separator + name;
        try {

            key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);


            ServerInit server = new MyFileServer();

            File video = new File(videoPath);
            FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(video);
            byte [] mydata=new byte[(int)video.length()];

            SealedObject sealed = new SealedObject(mydata, ecipher);

            int mylen=in.read(mydata);
            while(mylen>0){
                n.sendData(video.getName(), sealed, mylen);
                mylen=in.read(mydata);
            }

        }catch( Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void startServer(){
        try{


            ServerInit server = new MyFileServer();

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            registry.bind("videoServer", server);
            System.out.println(registry.lookup("videoServer"));

        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

**Client**

```
@Override
    public boolean sendData(String filename, SealedObject sealed, int len) throws RemoteException {
        try{
//            System.out.println("Here" );
//            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:./<policy>.policy");
//            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
//                System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
//            }

            key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            File f=new File(filename);
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f,true);
            //byte[] data = (byte[]) sealed.getObject(dcipher);
            System.out.println("Original Object: " + sealed );

            //out.write(data,0,len);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Done writing data...");
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Key distribution should have been mentioned in the assignment. If it wasn't, ask teacher. Maybe it is just assumed that the client has acquired the key offline. You certainly wouldn't send it over the insecure channel, and you can't seal it as you need, err, another key ...

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply. Should I use security manager aswell.

Comment: Not unless you're using the RMI codebase feature, or it's mentioned in the assignment. Generally to be avoided if possible.

Comment: Thanks @EJP for the help